# JavaFX, LineChart - How to set chosen Series to be always on top of the others?

Tags: javafx

I'm wondering if there is a way to decide which Series of LineChart should always be on top of the others?

In my program, Series on top is the latest updated one and sometimes covers another Series.

I want savings.Series to be always on top.

**I know i could fix that with changing methods order but maybe there is other way?**

Here is my code for application, it is solution of Java_Programming_MOOC_II/part14/part14-Part14_03.SavingsCalculator

```
package first;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

        VBox top = new VBox();
        top.setPadding(new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40));
        top.setSpacing(20);

        // Monthly savings UI
        BorderPane monthlyUI = new BorderPane();
        Label monthlySavingsLabel = new Label("Monthly savings");
        Slider monthsSlider = new Slider(25, 250, 0);
        Label monthsSliderValue = new Label(" 25");

        monthlySavingsLabel.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        monthsSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        monthsSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        monthlyUI.setLeft(monthlySavingsLabel);
        monthlyUI.setCenter(monthsSlider);
        monthlyUI.setRight(monthsSliderValue);

        //Yearly interest rate UI
        BorderPane interest = new BorderPane();
        Label yearlyInterestRateLabel = new Label("Yearly interest rate");
        Slider interestSlider = new Slider(0, 10, 0);
        Label interestSliderValue = new Label(" 0");

        yearlyInterestRateLabel.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));
        interestSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        interestSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        interest.setLeft(yearlyInterestRateLabel);
        interest.setCenter(interestSlider);
        interest.setRight(interestSliderValue);

        //Adding UIs to Vbox
        top.getChildren().addAll(monthlyUI, interest);

        //Setting Linechart
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 30, 1);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Savings");
        XYChart.Series savings = new XYChart.Series();
        savings.setName("Savings");
        XYChart.Series interestRate = new XYChart.Series();
        interestRate.setName("Interest rate");

        //Setting layout size
        layout.setPrefSize(800, 600);

        //Adding components to main layout
        layout.setTop(top);
        layout.setCenter(lineChart);
        
        //Adding funcionalities to sliders
        monthsSlider.valueProperty().addListener(event -> {
            String newLabel = "" + monthsSlider.getValue();
            if (newLabel.length() > 4) {
                newLabel = newLabel.substring(0, 5);
            }
            monthsSliderValue.setText(newLabel);
            updateSavingsSeries(savings, monthsSlider);
            updateInterestSeries(interestRate, interestSlider, monthsSlider);
        });

        interestSlider.valueProperty().addListener(event -> {
            String newLabel = "" + interestSlider.getValue();
            if (newLabel.length() > 4) {
                newLabel = newLabel.substring(0, 4);
            }
            interestSliderValue.setText(newLabel);
            updateInterestSeries(interestRate, interestSlider, monthsSlider);
        });
        
        //Setting first chart
        updateSavingsSeries(savings, monthsSlider);
        updateInterestSeries(interestRate, interestSlider, monthsSlider);
        lineChart.getData().add(savings);
        lineChart.getData().add(interestRate);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setTitle("SAVINGS CALCULATOR");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main.class);
    }

    public void updateSavingsSeries(XYChart.Series savingsSeries, Slider savingsSlider) {
        savingsSeries.getData().clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            double sum = savingsSlider.getValue() * 12 * i;
            savingsSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, sum));
        }
    }

    public void updateInterestSeries(XYChart.Series interestRateSeries, Slider interestRateSlider, Slider savingsSlider) {
        interestRateSeries.getData().clear();
        double rate = 1 + (interestRateSlider.getValue() / 100);
        double previousSum = 0;
        double finalSum = 0;
        interestRateSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, finalSum));
        for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
            finalSum = (previousSum + (savingsSlider.getValue() * 12)) * rate;
            interestRateSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, finalSum));
            previousSum = finalSum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you switch `lineChart.getData().add(savings);
        lineChart.getData().add(interestRate);` to `lineChart.getData().add(interestRate);
        lineChart.getData().add(savings);`

Comment: These methods work only for initial chart and changing it solves problem until we move any slider.
To make savings always on top we need to swap these two lines:
    updateSavingsSeries(savings, monthsSlider);
    updateInterestSeries(interestRate, interestSlider, monthsSlider);
However after swapping them, and setting interestSlider to 0, LineChart is showing points in interestRate.Series color and lines in savings.Series color

Comment: Just make sure that the series that you always want in the front in position zero.

Comment: Ok I got it for this case! 
Both Sliders in their methods must have 

`updateSavingsSeries(savings, monthsSlider);`

and of course it has to be the last modified series everywhere.
Thanks.

Comment: You can [answer you own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).